# Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 13.10 by running NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run.

I created a blacklist file under /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-file-drivers.conf and added nouveau to the list.

Also, I ran the installation after killing my display manager (sudo service lightdm stop). I'm working with gcc 4.8.

I'm getting the following error (from the installation log file):

ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if a driver such as rivafb, nvidiafb, or nouveau is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA graphics device(s), or no NVIDIA GPU installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.

Can someone please explain what the problem is and how can I fix it so I can finally install the drivers?

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the modprobe blacklist file (terminal: gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf) and add these entries at the bottom:

```
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

and save the file, then type

```
 "sudo update-initramfs -u"

now reboot
and install 
sh NV....run
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem persists (with the same error message in the log file).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it worked for me. Try proprietary drivers, install jockey-gtk, that should definitely help.

Comment: @GilLevi I solved the issue by following this post: [CUDA 6.5 on AWS GPU Instance Running Ubuntu 14.04](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/cuda-6-dot-5-on-aws-gpu-instance-running-ubuntu-14-dot-04/). Almost the same as this answer but maybe the difference helps.

Answer (score 0):

Manually install `nvidia-dkms-VERSION`, then, you will be able to skip on the kernel installation.

###### Example

```
sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-VERSION
```

*Replace **VERSION** accordingly of your (`NVIDIA-...VERSION.run`) executable file.*

###### Assume

1. [Blacklist Nvidia nouveau driver](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)
2. Stop the Desktop Manager by using `sudo telinit 3`